Python symlinks not working as Finder aliases
I'm writing some python code in JupyterLab and want to make symlinks that work in the Finder as aliases.  But using the Python os.symlink command doesn't work as an alias.  The Finder treats the destination as the source and complains because it's circular
I can reproduce it in a really simple case
src = '/Users/avirr/projects/symlink_test/text.txt'
# Destination file path
dst = '/Users/avirr/projects/symlink_test/test symlink'

os.symlink(src, dst)
os.readlink(dst)

result: '/Users/avirr/projects/symlink_test/text.txt'

I also tried Path(dst).symlink_to(src)
It doesn't work in the Finder that I can see:

